# Не работает функция авторизации

Tags: php, mysql

Делаю авторизацию по token'у и secret'ке. Не могу найти ошибку в логике, все равно показывает что данные неправильные. Когда делаю только по token'у, то все работает, а когда по 2 значениям - ошибка.

```
<?php
function _auth() {
    session_start();
    include 'connect.php';
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `users`";
    $result = mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql);

    while($user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $token=$user['token'];
        $secret=$user['secret'];
        if (isset($_POST['token'], $_POST['pass_btn'], $_POST['secret'])) {
            if ($token == $_POST['token'] and $secret == $_POST['secret']) {
                $_SESSION['unique_sdfcdrgbtrhbgfnb'] = true;
            } else {
                $_SESSION['sdfcdrgbtrhbgfnb'] = false;
                echo '<div>Failed token or secret</div>';
            }
        }
        if ($_SESSION['unique_sdfcdrgbtrhbgfnb'] !== true) {
            echo '<form method="POST">'.
              '<div>Enter token:<br /><input type="text" name="token" size="50" /></div>'.
               '<div>Enter secret:<br /><input type="text" name="secret" size="50" /></div>'.
               '<div><input type="submit" value="Enter" name="pass_btn" /></div>'.
               '</form>';
            die();
        }
    }
}
_auth();
?>
```

Comment: `$_SESSION['unique_sdfcdrgbtrhbgfnb'] = true;`  и далее по тексту `$_SESSION['sdfcdrgbtrhbgfnb'] = false;` это так задумано?

Comment: @ReinRaus именно так и задумано

Comment: ну так дебажите и ищите ошибку, у вас сейчас может `$user['secret']` совсем не тот, что в `$_POST['secret']`, потому и не работает. Самый простой способ дебага - внутри каждого условия/ветки else и за пределами условия делаете вывод уникального значения и смотрите где именно сломалась логика, т.е. смотрите по какой ветке пошел алгоритм. Затем смотрите почему пошло по этой ветке, а не по нужной, и т.д.

Answer (score 1):

По описанию, если через token - всё ок, то secret в БД хранится не в окрытом виде, а его хэш, например. Вы сравниваете скорее всего хэш с паролем.

Ещё момент. Не уверен, что тут нужно сравнивание с проверкой типа, в сессии хранится строка, если не ошибаюсь.

```
$_SESSION['unique_sdfcdrgbtrhbgfnb'] !== true
```